# Netlify Identity / GoTrue-js do user JWT expire?

Tags: javascript, jwt, netlify

Using https://github.com/netlify/gotrue-js to interface with netlify's authentication service (called "Identity") how frequently is it necessary to do the following:

```
const user = auth.currentUser();
const jwt = user.jwt();
jwt
  .then(response => console.log("This is a JWT token", response))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error fetching JWT token", error);
    throw error;
  });
```

Will the resulting JWT be valid forever? For the duration of the user's logged-in session? Or does it expire after a given amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `JWT`s contain can (optionally) contain an `exp` (expiration) claim, that contains the time when it will expire.

I don't have experience with `GoTrue`, but according to their [documentation](https://github.com/netlify/gotrue#configuration) you can configure the [expiration](https://github.com/netlify/gotrue#json-web-tokens-jwt), and it's set to a default value of 3600 seconds.

As the library also works with refresh tokens, you won't have to re-authenticate again after the token expires but use the refresh token to get a new access token.